# Multiple domains ecommerce tracking with google measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using the Google Measurement Protocol to track transaction hits in Google Analytics with Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking enabled. This works for my main domain, every transaction gets recorded in GA, even if it sometimes takes 24-48 hours.

I'm using multiple domains along with the same GA tracking code, and on this domains, when a transaction is recorded, **no hits are recorded in GA.**

I can't find any resources for this use case, but I guess that maybe it has something to do with the host parameter I'm sending. I'm doing a POST request to https://www.google-analytics.com/collect with a key=value body.

This is my main domain (example.com):

```
cid=1&cu=CHF&dh=example.com&dp=MyTitle&ds=server&pa=purchase&pr1ca=category1&pr1id=123&pr1nm=MyProduct&pr1pr=100.0&pr1qt=1&t=pageview&ti=ORDER123&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&tr=105.0&v=1
```

And this is my other domain (other-domain.com):

```
cid=1&cu=CHF&dh=other-domain.com&dp=MyTitle&ds=server&pa=purchase&pr1ca=category1&pr1id=123&pr1nm=MyProduct&pr1pr=100.0&pr1qt=1&t=pageview&ti=ORDER123&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&tr=105.0&v=1
```

I get a http status of 200 and response of `GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00`.

My analytics property is configured with a default URL of `http://example.com`.

Has anybody experienced a similar problem? **Does the  `dh` parameter has anything to do with the configured default URL?** Unfortunately, the docs are not very helpful in this case, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dh

Comment: the dh param does not interfere with the default URL maybe you can send the hit to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect so you get a validation of the hit.

Comment: First check is always to see if you have set up a hostname filter in the view settings. GA by itself does not care about the hostname. Base Url is only used in the preview feature and in-page analytics, it is not used in collection.

Comment: I didn't know about the debug output, so thanks for that! And I also checked the host filter, nothing there, but also a good and valid point to check. What I discovered while playing around: When I select a single day, the transaction is not showing. When I select multiple days (5 in my case) some of them are showing. So either google is taking longer than the usual 24-48h, or something else is wrong.